# what does 主張し合う mean?

Tags: words

in a manga about management, someone says 主張し合っても不味いだけ

Does this mean something like 'bring assertions together'? or come to an agreement when you have two different assertions/ideas that might not neccesarily fit together initially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase ... し合う, as in 愛し合う, 殺し合う, ののしり合う, denotes the ***reciprocal*** nature of the action in question: "they love ***each other***", "they kill ***one another***", "they hurl abuse at ***each other***".

In the case of 主張し合う,  they ***each*** (vehemently) voice their own conflicting opinions.

The phrase corresponds to "***s'entre***-tuer", "***s'entr*** aider" in French.

Answer (score 2):

If the people **insist on each one's own right/opinion/idea** *and never compromise*, it just doesn't work (or everyone just doesn't feel good).

The sentence means: "To compromise is a wise decision." "We have to compromise more or less in order to be happy/harmonious." or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to Seesawscene's answer, I think that the given sentence means only "no matter how much you guys insist on your opinion, you can never get good results".

Of course I understand it is natural that the speaker thought "to compromise is a wise decision" or something like that when he said the phrase.